# Elasticsearch: How to use "minimum_should_match" in match_phrase query?

Tags: elasticsearch, match-phrase

I'm new to Elasticsearch. I'm trying to search keywords in Elasticsearch with the **match_phrase**.

And I don't want to match all terms, so I add the **minimum_should_match** in search queries,  but it seems like it is impossible (ES doesn't support it).

What I need:

1. The **slop** of each term is 0 or bigger.
2. Matching terms must appear in their specified order.
3. It doesn't have to match every one of them. And I can specify any parameter such as the ** minimum_should_match**.

Anybody has experience on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you add some example docs and what you would like to match in each of them?